# over-coming interactive command in a script

Tags: command-line, scripts, password

I'm trying to have a script to create containers on proxmox, & I want user to enter his password before proceeding to the creation of container, so I can push it to the main command.

the command line that asks the user about his password is :

```
pct create ID Path_to_template  -password
```

during the process, the user will be asked to enter a new password, but I want to use the password I recieved earlier. is there a way to push it during the execution `pct` ?

is there anyway this can be done ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You should make your question more clear and understanding, see as well [how to ask a good question](//askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the relevant part of your script, along with which shell you're writing the script for.

Comment: @Videonauth "You should make your question more clear and understanding" isn't quite correct in English, it's the word understanding that doesn't work, 'easier to understand' or 'comprehensible' would be good substitutions. Just letting you know as I've seen you paste this elsewhere :)

Comment: @Arronical Thank you will adopt that into my script I use for pasting those comments.

Answer (score 1):

I found this simple script to get the job done:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Script to add a user to Linux system
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
    read -p "Enter username : " username
    read -s -p "Enter password : " password
    egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$username exists!"
        exit 1
    else
        pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
        useradd -m -p $pass $username
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a user!"
    fi
else
    echo "Only root may add a user to the system"
    exit 2
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) .Expect lets you automate user interaction on shell(entering password, ssh...).There you can find some examples that suit your needs. [Expect examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20TheGeekStuff%20(The%20Geek%20Stuff))

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.